# What do I need to write Japanese (kanji) on my Mac?

Tags: mac, tablet

I have a Macbook, but it's slightly [too old](https://superuser.com/questions/37435/can-i-write-japanese-on-my-trackpad) to use Mac OS X 10.6's trackpad Chinese input.

I have a Wacom tablet, but even though Mac OS X has had tablet character recognition since 10.2 and now knows Chinese characters, they're separate enough that it apparently can't put these two together and read Chinese characters I write on my Wacom.

But I'm sure *somebody* has a way to let me do this.  What software do I need to let me write Japanese kanji on my Wacom tablet under Mac OS X?

Comment: Seems like this is where a touchscreen computer could be handy with a touchscreen keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

[Tegaki](http://tegaki.org/) is open source Chinese/Japanese handwriting recognition software that supports Mac OS X.

Support for this feature is understandably limited in the mainstream. I lived in Japan for a few years, and keyboards are far-and-away the preferred input method of native Japanese writers.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the (poorly-named) [JavaDict](http://www.cs.arizona.edu/projects/japan/JavaDict/README.html), which lets me scribble kanji (with my mouse, even) and looks them up.

Unfortunately, it doesn't show stroke order (to let me know if I got it wrong), and it's really awkward for doing more than one, and the interface is ugly as sin, but the recognition part works pretty well.

Answer (score 0):

[Wacom Bamboo scribe](http://www.wacom.com.hk/downloads_detail.php?downloadsid=92), available for download via Wacom's Hong Kong website, allows Chinese, Japanese, and Korean input.  However, the Mac version only supports Intel Macs.